# Spring failed to load ApplicationContext while running TestNG test case - AutoProxyRegistrar.class cannot be opened

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, testng

I have a Spring MVC project using Hibernate ORM. When I try to make integration test with TestNG I get `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext`. Here is my stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TestContextTransactionUtils.retrieveTransactionManager(TestContextTransactionUtils.java:163)
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.getTransactionManager(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:361)
    ... 
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [kz.agrotrade.hibernate.HibernateTestConfig]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/context/annotation/AutoProxyRegistrar.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:546)
    ...
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/context/annotation/AutoProxyRegistrar.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
    ...
```

---

### Project structure:

[image: Project's test part structure]

---

Exception occurs when I'm trying to execute this test class:

```
package kz.agrotrade.hibernate;

import kz.agrotrade.domain.User;
import kz.agrotrade.testutil.Common;
import org.dbunit.dataset.IDataSet;
import org.dbunit.dataset.xml.FlatXmlDataSet;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.mockito.Spy;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


public class HibernateUserRepositoryTest extends HibernateRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    HibernateUserRepository userRepository;

    @Spy
    private User superman;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        superman = Common.getSuperman();
    }

    @Override
    protected IDataSet getDataSet() throws Exception {
        IDataSet dataSet = new FlatXmlDataSet(
                this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Users.xml"));
        return dataSet;
    }

    @Test
    public void findByLogin() {
        User user = userRepository.findByLogin("kent777");
        Assert.assertNotNull(user);
        Assert.assertEquals(user, superman);
    }

}
```

### HibernateRepositoryTest.java:

```
package kz.agrotrade.hibernate;


import org.dbunit.database.DatabaseDataSourceConnection;
import org.dbunit.database.IDatabaseConnection;
import org.dbunit.dataset.IDataSet;
import org.dbunit.operation.DatabaseOperation;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@ContextConfiguration(classes = {HibernateTestConfig.class})
public abstract class HibernateRepositoryTest extends AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        IDatabaseConnection dbConn = new DatabaseDataSourceConnection(dataSource);
        DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT.execute(dbConn, getDataSet());
    }

    protected abstract IDataSet getDataSet() throws Exception;

}
```

### HibernateTestConfig.java

```
package kz.agrotrade.hibernate;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("kz.agrotrade")
public class HibernateTestConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("kz.agrotrade");
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/agro-core");
        dataSource.setUsername("agro");
        dataSource.setPassword("agropass");
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
        return txManager;
    }

}
```

I am not exactly sure whats causing the issue. How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Do you reproduce the issue outside eclipse? For example, try with maven only.

Comment: @JulienHerr, I ran `mvn test` and found the core of the problem - `A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling`. I just added annotation `@WebAppConfiguration` to my test class and problem disappeared. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to close the question: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mr. Julien Herr advised, I ran my test with maven only and encountered with the `A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling` error. So the solution is to add `@WebAppConfiguration` to the test class:

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {HibernateTestConfig.class})
public abstract class HibernateRepositoryTest extends AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        IDatabaseConnection dbConn = new DatabaseDataSourceConnection(dataSource);
        DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT.execute(dbConn, getDataSet());
    }

    protected abstract IDataSet getDataSet() throws Exception;

}
```